# Eclipse update has broken my IDE

Tags: android, eclipse

I just ran the eclipse update process and now have at least two problems.
1. The xml editor no longer works
2. The new entries into the Resources\raw directory do not generate entries in R.raw
The version information is:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

Does anyone have any idea what has happened?
I knew I should not do an update, they always end in tears.

I should add I am getting these messages.

Error
Fri Mar 02 00:09:05 EST 2012
Could not create content describer for org.eclipse.wb.core.javaSourceGUI. Content type has been disabled.

Error
Fri Mar 02 00:09:05 EST 2012
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wb.core (496).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a fresh Eclipse installation and configure it to your needs.

For your next update you should do the same and use the old one as long as it takes to have the new version fully functional.

Comment: I know you are right, I should not have relied on the update process. I have been caught a couple of million times before, you would think I would learn.

Comment: Well that cost several hours. Looks like a fresh install has got me back on track. I won't make that mistake again...HA!

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the `/gen` directory and then doing Project > Clean. ADT has some bugs in the area of re-building generated code under some circumstances; I've never been able to narrow them down to a reproducible test case, but deleting `/gen` and cleaning usually fixes things up for me.

Comment: Tried this and failed, answer was a fresh eclipse/SDK install

Answer (score 0):

You can change compiler in eclipse go to project  properties and change java compiler form 1.6 to 1.5. I have faced this problem many times; R.java not generated. This issues is comes from res folder. You have any error in layout.

For example if you are using api level 7 and you are defining match_parent in your layout then this problem occured and you can not get any error when you run your project see only red line below(R.layout)

Comment: Yes, Pradeep I have had that problem in the past but it is not the issue this time.